# Identity of a Mathematician Mentioned in Euler

Tags: elementary-number-theory, math-history, magic-square

I and several others are in the process of translating one of Euler's papers from Latin to English, in particular the one that the Euler Archive lists as [E36](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/pages/E036.html). In it Euler proves the Chinese Remainder Theorem, but my question is this:

In Section 1, Euler refers to two (presumably mathematicians) named in Latin as *Lahirii* and *Sauwerii*. The Latin is as follows:

> Ita **quadratorum magicorum** constructio iam pridem ab arithmeticis est tradita; qua autem cum esset insufficiens maiora ingenia ***Lahirii*** et ***Sauwerii*** ad perficiendum requisivit.

We are reasonably confident that *Lahirii* refers to [Philippe de La Hire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippe_de_La_Hire) as he did in fact work on magic squares (*quadratorum magicorum*), but we have no clue as to the identity of *Sauwerii* and can find no mention of a mathematician named Sawyer who worked on magic squares.

Does anyone know who this might refer to?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The identity of Sauwerii can be found in a footnote of a publication of the first part of *Commentationes arithmeticae*. Specifically, [**here**](http://books.google.com/books?id=QaEJdhNK_EUC&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=sauwerii&source=bl&ots=KNc55rUAil&sig=4q2pZr_EmqASKSIZtm9QIkedowU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YenmUq_rEKTCywG6yoGQAg&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=sauwerii&f=false).

Euler is referring to a [Joseph Sauveur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Sauveur), 1653-1716. More specifically, he is referring to Sauveur's paper *Construction generale des quarres magiques* (accents omitted), which appeared in Mem. de l'acad. d. sc. de Paris [academy of sciences of Paris], 1710, p. 92.

Comment: +1 Good detective work, Newb! The worth of this forum proves itself once again. (P.S. Unfortunately, Sauveur doesn't even have an entry at http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Indexes/S.html.)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Thanks! It appears that Sauveur is quite obscure; he doesn't have an entry in the Mathematics Genealogy Project, either. However, his Wikipedia page is quite extensive. It appears that his greatest impacts were in acoustics, allegedly more or less founding this field of study. So perhaps it makes sense that he's not chiefly thought of as a mathematician.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a reference to Sauveur in Sandifer's book, "The Early Mathematics of Leonhard Euler", in the chapter about E-36.

For a preview, see:
http://books.google.com/books?id=CvBxLr_0uBQC&pg=PA351